# Ocaml calling function without giving right number of arguments

Tags: function, arguments, ocaml

If I have a function in ocaml specified by:

```
let rec new_grammar rules nonterm  = 
  match rules with 
  | (expr, rules) -> if expr = nonterm then ............
```

and I call it in another place by saying `new_grammar rules`

How does expr know if its equal to nonterm since I didn't feed in the argument for nonterm

Comment: In FP you don't call a function, you write an expression which  is evaluated by the system. Evaluation of `new_grammar rules` yields a function ready to accept the argument `nonterm`. This is the basics of currying.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply function without giving a full number of arguments or, in OCaml parlance, when you make a partial application, then the resulting value will be a function, that will take the rest arguments, and evaluate to the expected return value.

Example, if you have function `sum` defined as:

```
let sum x y = x + y
```

and later you apply it partially to one argument:

```
let plus_2 = sum 2
```

then `plus_2` would be an unary function of type `int -> int`, accepting one argument (namely `y`) and adding to it `2` (and argument assigned to a formal parameter `x`)